# HDF5 access restrictions on data subsets

Tags: hdf5, opendap

Short question: Is there a way to allow different user permissions/ access restrictions in HDF5?

We are currently thinking of setting up a Hyrax server providing different users with HF5 files. However, some users should only be allowed to grab different subsets of the data contained in *one* HDF5 file.

I know that HDF5 is not designed for this task but does someone know if it works or if there is any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box HDF5 doesn't support restricting access to (parts of) a single file.

I expect that with enough cunning on your part you could write your own [file driver](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/Tutor/filedrvr.html) to implement the type of access restrictions you want.

Personally I think it would be easier to write a utility to split a multi-restriction-domain file into single-restriction-domain parts and to unsplit and maintain consistency.  Even easier would be to not design files on which you want to place different access restrictions to different groups or datasets.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for but the one I expected. +1 for the file driver info